# How to get started with OSMDroid

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, osmdroid

I am working on offline map using OSMDroid libraries. I have imported osmdroi-android-3.0.5.jar and slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar. I am following this [link.](http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30) But, I can not see the map. It shows only a white blank screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I was making an error while importing reference libraries osmdroi-android-3.0.5.jar and slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar.
Once the libraries are placed in libs folder of the project. Right click to the jar file and select Build Path. These files will be placed in a referenced libraries folder of the project. Now again right click the jar files in referenced libraries and select Build Path ---> Configure Build Path. In the libraries tab select osmdroi-android-3.0.5.jar and edit its source attachment and Javadoc location.
For source attachment see the snapshot[Snapshot of source attachment configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsW9g.png)
For Javadoc location see the snapshot[Snapshot of Javadoc location configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFmZ9.png).

OSMdroid001 is the project name in my snapshot.